# Call controller from submit button with CodeIgniter

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm loading a view and I'm passing 2 arguments from a controller like this:

```
$this->load->view('confirm_data_v', $data);
```

In confirm_data_v view I'm receiving $data that is an array. In confirm_data_v I have a Submit button, but I want to call another controller when I click on it. The code of the button in confirm_data_v is:

```
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

confirm_data_v is a view to confirm to the user the information that he gave, so when he clicks "Save" button, it calls the controller to save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You cant normally call a controller directly from a view - but you dont need to just make the button redirect to or ajax call any url you like (mysite.com/myurl in this example) on the button click and then route that to your controller:

```
$route['myurl'] = 'mycontroller';
```

Your main options for storing the data between the two pages are either storing in a session or a cookie or echoing all their data into hidden form fields and re-posting it (if it's sensative data - go with the session option):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

If for whatever you really do want to call a controller from a view you ca do it using wiredesigns modular codeigniter : https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

But generally speaking this flies in the face of the mvc architecture and there is no need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What i have get from your question that you want to submit data to controller n#1 from the view after loading it from a controller n#2

if this is the case you can do

**Method # 1**

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/function'); ?>   
 <div class = "container">
            <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and you can access any other value with `$this->post->input('input_name')`

**Method # 2**
use Anchor instead of submit button

```
<div class = "container">
        <div class="form-actions">
           <?php echo anchor('controller/function/parm','Save',array('class'=>'btn btn-success')); ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

and in your controller for example

```
function confirm_save($parm)
{
   //save to database
   //redirect back to the next controller you want with success message for example using session flash data
   //or load another view but URL will be still the same whatever suits your case 
}
```